# javascript, jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, head

I have some questions about jquery and javascript. I have a code that is not working because of jquery conflict, I believe its because of version, decompressed or compressed (I'm not clear). The part of my code with the jquery is as below:

```
<head>
<meta name="server-time" content="04/08/2014 09:57:32">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/container.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css_main_az.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabs.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="widgets-min.css" title="default"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tipped.css"/>

<script src="css/modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widgets-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="spinners.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tipped.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="css/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="animatedcollapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
</head>
```

Can you guys help me pinpoint the conflicting jquery, and also do i need to include all of those other javascript if I already loaded in from the jquery? for example do i need to reference the animatedcollapse.js if it's already in the jquery library? Lastly what do I need to do to fix this conflicting code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are including too many versions of jQuery! I see at least 4 references. Pick one!

Comment: also, you load two jquery libraries jquery-1.7.2.min.js AND http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: what do you recommend that I pick?

Comment: @StrikeNeo unfortunately some of them are so old that it's unlikely that the plugin that uses it will support the latest version. You need to decide on a version then find jquery plugins that work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the `jquery` library multiple times. The following are redundant, choose one, and remove the rest. You probably want the jquery script to be the first one after your css `<link>`s

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Probably not a bad idea to grab the most recent version from [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/) and use that. Currently there are 2 choices (1.11.0 and 2.1.0) I'd suggest 1.11.0 unless you are ok disregarding older versions of internet explorer

Comment: Ok after I choose 1, the jquery1.7.2.min.js, I remove the rest. Now some function does not behave as before. For example the animatedcollapse.js does not functioning with the jquery 1.7.2.min.js. How do I fix this? do I need to find a different version of animatedcollapse.js? thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: *"do I need to find a different version of animatedcollapse.js"* Yes. just find plugins that do support jquery 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading 4 version of jQuery, you should call only one

```
<script src="css/modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widgets-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="spinners.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tipped.js"></script>
<script src="css/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="animatedcollapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>`
```